# Empty UITapGestureRecognizer buffer

Tags: objective-c, ios, buffer, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to design a really simple card game. The functionality basically consists on discovering the cards in order just tapping on them. To do this I put the cards on a UIView, and I overlay other UIView where I capture the taps. Then I just calculate which card has been tapped and I flip it.

The problem is that if I tap a wrong card, this tap appears to remain in a kind of buffer, and when I tap another card, sometimes a previous card tapped flips without being tapped. Is this buffer real or I'm doing something else wrong? If this buffer is real, how can I delete its content every time I capture a new tap?

Thanks in advance.

> Problem solved :)
>   Here is the part of the code where the problem was, between
>   tapping the card and checking if it is a king.

**[...] some code here [...]**

```
// And if what we have found is a king, then we uncover the next card in the game stack and .

if ([[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] cardValue] == 9) {

//[self uncoverTheNextCardToPlay];

    do {

        [self uncoverTheNextCardToPlay];

    } while ([[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] cardValue] == 9 && gameWindow.lastIndex < 40);
}

// And we update the realIndex with the real index index of the card just uncovered.

gameWindow.realIndex = ([[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] cardSuit]*10)+[[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] cardValue];
```

**[...] more code here [...]**

```
- (void)uncoverTheNextCardToPlay
{
    gameWindow.lastIndex = gameWindow.lastIndex+10;

    [[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] setCover:NO];

    [[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] refreshCardWithCardBack:gameWindow.cardBack];

    gameWindow.realIndex = ([[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] cardSuit]*10)+[[gameWindow.deck getCardAtIndex:gameWindow.lastIndex] cardValue];
}
```

Comment: The docs make no mention of an internal buffer - [link](http://bit.ly/a0T2Cp). Perhaps you are making a mistake where you "calculate which card has been tapped". Post some code so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, that was my main problem. I didn't find anything about this buffer, but still its effects appear in my application (as Higgs bosom). Give me a few hours to double check my code and to extract a part of it to try to show you where I have the problem. Thanks.

Comment: So finally, after 8 hours coding I have found a redundant instruction that create double referencies to the same variable almost simultaneously, so more than one card were discovered in a fraction of second! Thanks for your help @Barjavel. You where right and **the buffer was a lie**. Sometimes the best answer is the one that avoid you loosing time looking in wrong directions :)